# what is my iphone app's design pattern

Tags: iphone, design-patterns

I have an iphone app which is a tabbar based application. What is the design pattern of my app. Sorry for asking a fundamental question, i am not aware of design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabbar  doesn't imply any design pattern. It is just UI element that represent some data.
Your app can use several design patterns. For example for data representation it is probably MVC (model-view-controller) pattern.

Read this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29). As you can see there are tons of patterns and they are almost always mixed in your app.

Answer (score 0):

A [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) is just a commonly found approach to commonly occurring problems in computer science. It's usually used in reference to object-oriented programming design patterns such as those described by the [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). We could not identify the specific design patterns you used without looking at your code as a whole.